# Searching multiple mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have this code.

```
            switch($search_topic)
            {
                case 'Title':
                    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT game_id, title, platform_name, author_name, price
                                            FROM games 
                                            WHERE title 
                                            LIKE :search_term");
                break;

                case 'Platform':
                    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT game_id, title, platform_name, author_name, price
                                            FROM games 
                                            INNER JOIN platforms ON games.platform_id = author.platform_id
                                            WHERE platform_name LIKE :search_term");
                break;
            }
```

the search_topic variable is coming from a listbox on the previous webpage, the Title search works correctly as its simply just search one MySQL table. The Platform search is being abit difficult as I'm attempting to search multiple tables, If that makes sense.

The games table has a column called "platform_id" this this links to the platform table where the key field links to what platform it is under. So how would I go about getting the "platform_id" from the games table and then link it to the "platforms" so I retieve the "platform_title" and then use that to search against.

Schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d3e3/6

Comment: Is it just that your join is bad? Shouldn't it be `... ON games.platform_id = platforms.id`

Comment: I'd *highly* recommend you build a schema with data we can play with over at sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Well spotted, After correction the search still doesn't work as expected, thanks for noticing though!

Comment: I'll create the schema now!

Comment: Done! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d3e3/6 I've put the title search as an example, as that one works! I just need to get the platform search working now

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect the correction by @hafichuk

Comment: I think you killed sqlfiddle!

Comment: @Strawberry LOL - I just checked the fiddle again and am getting a blank page too. Think of all of those SO users who only have half of an answer now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off of your fiddle, here's the update for you:

```
SELECT g.game_id, g.title, p.platform_name, a.author_name, g.price
FROM games g
INNER JOIN platforms p ON p.platform_id = g.platform_id
INNER JOIN author a ON a.author_id = g.author_id
WHERE g.title LIKE 'Skyrim';
```

You would obviously change `WHERE g.title LIKE 'Skyrim';` to whichever field you would like to filter on. So the platform query would be:

```
SELECT g.game_id, g.title, p.platform_name, a.author_name, g.price
FROM games g
INNER JOIN platforms p ON p.platform_id = g.platform_id
INNER JOIN author a ON a.author_id = g.author_id
WHERE p.platform_name LIKE 'Xbox';
```

I would also suggest that you change your CHARSET to utf8 instead of latin1, assuming this reflects your production database setup.

Comment: You star! It works perfectly, thank you very much! If I wanted to search for an author, would it simply be a chase of changing the where statement to a.author_name LIKE 'Something'?

Comment: This makes very little sense, The platform search was working before. The code still works if I run it on phpmyadmin and it displays the correct results but if on my website, its returning the incorrect information. Yet the code is the same? What could have caused this?

Comment: I'd suggest that you take a look at the mysql.log and see what SQL is actually being run when doing it through your site. I usually find this from the command line at `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`. If you can't find the issue, I'd suggest posting this as a new question ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT games.game_id, 
games.title, 
games.platform_name, 
games.author_name, 
games.price, 
games.platform_id, 
platforms.platform_id,
platforms.platform_name
FROM games, platforms 
WHERE
games.platform_id = platforms.platform_id
AND
platform.platform_name LIKE %:search_term%
```

Comment: Love the pre-SQL92. Old school!